# preProcess function R

Tags: r, preprocessor

I'm very new to R.

I'm trying to follow the procedure below:

```
imputedData <- preProcess( select(train, -SalePrice),
  method = c("center", "scale", "knnImpute", "nzv", 'YeoJohnson')
  )
#install.packages('RANN')
library(RANN)
trainTrans <- predict(imputedData, train)
```

And I have this error

`Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript` nn$nn.idx `must be a simple vector, not a matrix.`

I have already install Caret package

The train dataset is a table that I have imported from a CSV file

Comment: i cannot reproduce your error. you really encounter the error at the predict() ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the program

#### Loading of packages

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(GGally)
library(lattice)
library(corrplot)
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)
library(magrittr)
theme_set(theme_bw())
set.seed(181019)
```

#### Data loading

```
train <- readr::read_csv("train.csv")
test  <- readr::read_csv("test.csv")
```

#### Missing value

```
missing_threshold <- .4
is_too_scarce <- lapply(select(train, -SalePrice), function(x) mean(is.na(x)) > missing_threshold)
is_too_scarce <- map_lgl(select(train, -SalePrice), ~mean(is.na(.x)) > missing_threshold)
not_too_scarce <- names(is_too_scarce)[!is_too_scarce]
train <- select(train, SalePrice, not_too_scarce)
train %<>% select(SalePrice, not_too_scarce)
test  %<>% select(not_too_scarce)
```

#### Preprocessing

```
imputedData <- preProcess( select(train, -SalePrice),
  method = c("center", "scale", "knnImpute", "nzv", 'YeoJohnson')
  )
#install.packages('RANN')
library(RANN)
testTrans  <- predict(imputedData, test)
trainTrans <- predict(imputedData, train)
```